# How to use JS/jQuery to switch between two partial views on one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a report that can be viewed in two ways: Summary or Detail. The page loads the Summary partial view as default. At the top of the page are two buttons, Summary and Detail. What I want to happen is when I click the Detail button I want the Detail partial view to load over the Summary partial and vice versa.

Is there a way I can use Javascript to load the partial view that corresponds to the button that is clicked?

This is the div on the main view that loads as default:

```
       <div data-listen="start_date end_date" data-contentrequest="_Summary" data-requestonload="true">
       </div>
```

Comment: When you say load over, are you talking about a visual / UI change, or does the page need to make a request back to the server when the detail is clicked?  Also, are you loading both partials up front and hiding one or just loading the summary partial?

Comment: Yup, your view & data are not the same, switching the view is easy you could  do it a many ways, turn off one element for example and switch the other on, perhaps using Jquery.fadeIn / FadeOut, ideally you want to use knockout/ember/angular or other framework if you need to alot of switching views with data, as your app essentially becomes a SPA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish your task. I am assuming that it is acceptable to make a server side call in your situation. This approach will work in a simple application. As your application grows complex you can look into other MVVM frameworks as suggested by saj

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <button data-url = '@Url.Action("Summary","SomeController")' >Summary</button>
    <button data-url = '@Url.Action("Details","SomeController")'>Detail</button>
</div>

<div id="divContent" data-listen="start_date end_date" data-contentrequest="_Summary" data-requestonload="true">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
   $(function () {
    $("button").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            cache: false,
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            success: function (data, xhr, settings) {
                $("#divContent").html(data);
            }

        });
    });
});
```

**Controller Methods**

```
public class SomeController : Controller
    {
     public ActionResult Summary()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }

        public ActionResult Details()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
}
```

Comment: love the use of a custom event to really DRY out the code!

Comment: This looks exactly like what I want to do. The only thing I'm struggling with is figuring out the right path to put in the JavaScript to refer to the Controller with the summary and detail functions.

Comment: I have edited the answer to use the UrlHelper function. This way you can build your Url in the view rather than hardcoding in the JS function.